# XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2eff, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002eff error when making a POST request in IE 11

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-11

I have an issue that started cropping up recently that I'm unable to resolve.
This only happens on IE11. On other browsers like Chrome, Firefox and Edge this issue does not appear.

The problem is a particular POST request I make is frequently timing out. It looks something like

```
Url: https://mysite/api/v1/myapi

POST data: {"event": "xxx", "data": "{\"attr1\":\"val\", \"attr2":\"val2\"}"}

Request headers:
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 90
Content-Type: application/json
Host: xxx
Referer: xxx
User-Agent: xxx
X-CSRFToken: xxx
```

Sorry cannot post the exact data of the request, but this is the gist of it.

When making the web request we do it in javascript using an XMLHttpRequest object.
When the page loads I bring up the IE browser console and switch to the network tab. When it gets up to this request it's stuck on (pending) and I see an error in the console that looks like:

```
XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2eff, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002eff
```

This error doesn't happen on every page load. It seems to be non deterministic. Sometimes the page will load and this api request will get made and return a 200 as expected.
The web page in question also makes a number of other web requests to the same site and they all complete successfully in IE.

I have looked for this problem in other StackOverflow questions and based on one of the answers, I noticed that if I disable TLS 1.2 in the InternetExplorer advanced options then this request completes successfully all the time.
With that said clearly that's not a good solution for the problem.

I have tried to manually instantiate the XMLHttpRequest object with the POST data, and request headers, and call it directly from the IE web console. In this case it calls the api fine without any issues and returns the 200 response as expected. I find it really strange that I'm able to make this request manually after

Based on our Sentry logs it appears this issue only started happening recently (around end of May). I was investigating if there was Windows 10 OS update that was responsible, but nothing came up immediately.

If anyone has any ideas/suggestions of what to try, would be great. I have been looking at this for two days and don't think like I'm making much headway.

Comment: Can you please tell me your OS build and the exact version of the IE 11 browser? I can try to check whether there is any known issue with the update you are using. for testing purposes, you can try to pass the type: post and data: data as a separate parameter. See whether it makes any difference in that way. I have also found that if you are trying to pass the data without '\' then also it works. So you can also try to test without using '\' in your data. Try to put some delay if you are doing multiple requests.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
IE version is 11.1039.17763.0 (Update versions 11.0.175)
Have also tried it on a couple of other VMs with the same issue. Not sure if the versions there are exactly the same.
The '\' being a problem did come up in another SO thread I read. I thought this was not the problem though because when I replicated this by creating the XMLHttpRequest directly I did make sure to also copy the \ characters, and it was working fine there. With that said it's worth looking into a bit more, will let you know if I make progress with that.

Comment: After doing the software update my IE version is now: 11.900.18362.0 Update version 11.0195. It's still happening though.

Comment: Does this happen with any specific page or it can occur on any page of your site? Did you noticed any pattern when this issue occurs?

Comment: I've spent some more time looking at it today. It can happen on any page of the site (as this api is called on many different pages). I've been refreshing a particular page where this happens and the request headers are identical in both loads, however in one instance I'm getting the network error in the XMLHttpRequest and in the next load the api succeeds without any issue. Seems like it is completely random. I've been trying to find a pattern but no luck. Will it help if I give you a url that you can hit so you can see it yourself?

Comment: Try to increase the timeout. Try to use HTTPS if you are using the HTTP. Add the site in the trusted site list. If the issue persists then for testing purposes, try to test the issue with the lower security settings to see whether it makes any difference.